# How to separate a string using separator

Tags: c++

I want to separate this string using _ as the separators

```
{[Data1]_[Data2]_[Data3]}_{[Val1]_[Val2]}_{[ID1]_[ID2]_[ID3]}
```

where underscore should not be considered inside the {   }  brackets.

so when we separate the strings we should have three new data items

```
 {[Data1]_[Data2]_[Data3]}
 {[Val1]_[Val2]}
 {[ID1]_[ID2]_[ID3]}
```

currently I was separating using boost

```
        std::vector<std::string> commandSplitSemiColon;
        boost::split(commandSplitSemiColon, stdstrCommand, boost::is_any_of("_"), 
        boost::token_compress_on);
```

but how can we ignore the underscore inside the { } brackets and only consider underscore which are not inside the brackets.

Comment: If it's guaranteed that there are at most 1 nesting layer of braces some regex can. Otherwise just do it manually

Comment: Split at `}_{` instead of the underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A manual solution: iterate through the string and use a variable to check whether it's in the bracket or not:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::string s = "{[Data1]_[Data2]_[Data3]}_{[Val1]_[Val2]}_{[ID1]_[ID2]_[ID3]}";
std::string token = "";
bool inBracket = false;
for (char c : s) {
    if (c == '{') {
        inBracket = true;
        token += c;
    }
    else if (c == '}') {
        inBracket = false;
        token += c;
    }
    else if (c == '_' && !inBracket) {
        strings.push_back(token);
        token = "";
    }
    else {
        token += c;
    }
}

if (!token.empty()) {
    strings.push_back(token);
}
```

Comment: If you change `bool inBracket` to `int inHowManyBrackets` you can handle nested brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you note the similarity between your format and conventional CSV (comma-separated value), you can search for existing solutions.

For example, on this forum: [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c). Specifically, using Boost Tokenizer with escaped_list_separator